# Publish my map from ArcGIS Pro as a WMS

Tags: arcgis-pro, wms

I'd like to use layers of lot boundaries from a map I created in another application. The application can link to WMS to get that content, but I'm not sure how to set up my map as a WMS that I can link to.

Can I set up a WMS from ArcGIS Pro? Do I need special privileges like ArcGIS Server?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro is a desktop application, to set up a WMS you'll need a server application